# Flutter Full Screen Intent notificaiton

Tags: flutter, android-intent, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am facing issues with Getting my app to receive phone calls video and audio with a full screen notification like receiving a normal call

I have tried this code below on the background of the app it sometimes appear.

```
await LaunchApp.openApp(
  androidPackageName: 'com.example.commute',
  iosUrlScheme: 'pulsesecure://',
  appStoreLink: 'itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/us/app/pulse-secure/id945832041',
  // openStore: false
);
```

but when the app is killed it doesn't work or when the app is on some other device it doesn't work.